# ValueError when reshaping DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that looks something like this :

```
['3G LOJISTIK VE HAVACILIK HIZMETLARI LTD.', ' No. 3/182 Altintepe\r\nBagdat Cad. Istasyon Yolu Sok.', ' Istanbul 34840', ' Turkey', ' Additional\r\nSanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [SDGT]\r\n[IFSR] ', '.\r\n\r\n7 KARNES', ' Avenida Ciudad de Cali No. 15A-91', ' Local A06-07', ' Bogota', '\r\nColombia', ' Matricula Mercantil No 1978075 ', ' [SDNTK].']
```

I converted the list into a pandas DataFrame I want to reshape in a way that the first 7 elements get stored as the first row and the next 7 as the second row ( and if there are less than 7 elements the messing elements get filled with 0 )

I tried the following code but I get this error `ValueError: 7 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns`

```
 text_cleaned = text_cleaner(raw_text)
            st.title('Structured Data : ')
            df = pd.DataFrame(text_cleaned)
            df = (pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df.index // 7)
                               .apply(list)
                               .values
                               .tolist(), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']).fillna(0))
```

Comment: please post the expected dataframe based on the input list for validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **pad** it and **reshape** it using **numpy**

```
a = np.array(['3G LOJISTIK VE HAVACILIK HIZMETLARI LTD.', ' No. 3/182 Altintepe\r\nBagdat Cad. Istasyon Yolu Sok.', ' Istanbul 34840', ' Turkey', ' Additional\r\nSanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [SDGT]\r\n[IFSR] ', '.\r\n\r\n7 KARNES', ' Avenida Ciudad de Cali No. 15A-91', ' Local A06-07', ' Bogota', '\r\nColombia', ' Matricula Mercantil No 1978075 ', ' [SDNTK].'])
a = np.pad(a,(0,7-a.shape[0]%7))
pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(a.shape[0]//7,7), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
```